# watir select_list regex variable NoValueFoundException

Tags: ruby, regex, variables, selectlist

Ruby newbie and needing some assistance.  Passed variable to select_list and i want to find the 1st option that matches the variable.

The list options are:

- Portland
- Portland, ME
- Portland, Or

...and I assigned the city to variable

```
var="Portland"
```

Using:
    `f.select_list(:id => /location/).select(/var/)`

gives `NoValueFoundException`

but when i use...

```
`f.select_list(:id => /location/).select(/Portland/) #no exception, gives 1st entry`
```

How can i access the first option using regex and variables?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the literal regular expression /var/, you need to construct the Regular expression from the string value of the variable var.

Example:

```
:001 > /hello/.match('hello world')
 => #<MatchData "hello"> 
:002 > exp = 'hello'
 => "hello" 
:003 > /exp/.match('hello world')
 => nil 
:004 > Regexp.new(exp).match('hello world')
 => #<MatchData "hello">
```